# Is $(1+m)^{1/m} < (1+\frac{1}{m})^m$?

Tags: inequality

If  $(1+\frac{1}{m})^m<e$; $m \in N $

How can we prove $(1+m)<e^m$ ?

I've been able to prove that above statement by mathematical induction but I'm unable to see it as a direct consequence of the give statement above.

If I can prove this $(1+m)^{1/m} < (1+\frac{1}{m})^m$ without using mathematical induction I shall be able to rest my case. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [**Bernoulli inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

$$(1+m)^{1/m}\le1+\frac1m m=2<e$$

and

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^m\ge 1+m\frac 1m=2$$

As an alternative by [**AM-GM inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

$$(1+m)^{1/m}=\sqrt[m]{\overbrace{1\cdot 1\cdot \ldots \cdot(1+m)}^{m\, terms}}\le \frac{\overbrace{1+ 1+ \ldots +(1+m)}^{m\, terms}}{m}=\frac{2m}m=2$$

Comment: The inequality is not strict. And can you provide a proof which doesn't use bernoulii??

Comment: @JyotishrajThoudam From the first one we obtain $$(1+m)^{1/m}\le1+\frac1m m=2<e$$ and equality holds only for $m=1$.

Comment: @JyotishrajThoudam I've added an alternative by AM-GM.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually $(1+\frac1m)^{m}<e$ holds for all $m\geq 0$. Thus in particular for $m'=\frac1m$ the inequality holds. By substitution we obtain
$$(1+m')^{1/m'}<e$$ from which you conclude using that functions of the type $x^q$ are increasing for all $q\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively note that
$$ e^m = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{m^j}{j!} = 1 + m + \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{m^j}{j!} > 1+m, $$
for $m > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall **Bernoulli's inequality**:

> $$(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx, \forall x>-1.$$

Thus,we have $$1+m=\left(1+m^2 \cdot \frac{1}{m}\right)\leq \left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m^2}=\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m}\right]^m\leq e^m. $$